# How to apply pattern match when needed to match a middle element of a Seq() in scala

Tags: list, scala, pattern-matching

This is kind of a learning question rather than a programming code, I have a Sequence as below,

```
val inputSeq = Seq("A","B","C","D","E")
```

so I want to identify an inside element (in this case "C") from the sequence using pattern matching and  apply pattern matching as in the following example to add an element,

```
val modified = inputSeq match {

case first_part +: "C" +: tail => first_part +: "C" +: "D" +: tail
case _ => ???
}
```

I know there are other ways that I can use without pattern matching. However, I want to know how I can achieve this using pattern matching. However, I can't match the `first_part` as a sequence, can someone help me to find a way to match the first_part as a sequence?

Comment: You could use `case a :: b :: "C" :: tail` but this only works if you know the position of "C" beforehand and you still get the "heads" as separate items.

Comment: Not really possible with pattern matching AFAIK. A good reason to avoid such syntax is that it would hide very expensive operations from anyone reading the code.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not exactly what you're aiming at, but here's one way to do it by pattern matching recursively:

```
val inputSeq = Seq("A","B","C","D","E")

def modifyList(seq: Seq[String], s: String, t: String): List[String] = {
  @scala.annotation.tailrec
  def loop(ls: List[String], res: List[String]): List[String] = ls match {
    case Nil => res.reverse
    case `s` :: tail => loop(tail, t :: s :: res)
    case h :: tail => loop(tail, h :: res)
  }
  loop(seq.toList, Nil)
}

modifyList(Seq("A","B","C","D","E"), "C", "D")
// List(A, B, C, D, D, E)

modifyList(Seq("A","B","C","D","E","C","F"), "C", "X")
// List(A, B, C, D, X, E, C, X, F)
```

Note that the above sample code simply appends to every occurrence of the string being matched against (i.e. `s`) with the provided string `t`.